# With a connection to remote mysql server in netbeans, how to print out the data using either java or javaEE

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have already connected to the remote server in **NetBeans**.

I can see the table and schema under **Database** in **Service**. However, I am wondering whether I need to write some code to connect to the remote database again or if I can just **re-use the existing connection** to print out the data. I need to process the data, so I can just use SQL to get the data.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't understand your question. You want your program, written in Java, to connect to a database. And you expect that it's possible without writing code to connect to the database? Is that your question? If so, no, that's obviously not possible. Read the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html

Comment: Maybe you would get more help on this question if you provided more information for what you are trying to do. Are you trying to connect to the database from a program you are writing? Or something else?

Comment: ya, i just realized how stupid this question is...